# Rails 4 production issue with elasticsearch logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, heroku, logging

I am implementing Elasticsearch on Heroku in a rails 4.2.11.3 app with ruby 2.5.0 for basic search of the User model. In the heroku staging environment, it works perfectly, but in the production environment, I am encountering this error when importing the model.

```
irb(main):001:0> User.import
Traceback (most recent call last):
       16: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:16:in `visit'
       15: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:208:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
       14: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:374:in `revive'
       13: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:336:in `revive_hash'
       12: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:336:in `each_slice'
       11: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:336:in `each'
       10: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:338:in `block in revive_hash'
        9: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:32:in `accept'
        8: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
        7: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:16:in `visit'
        6: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:208:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
        5: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:391:in `resolve_class'
        4: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/class_loader.rb:28:in `load'
        3: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/class_loader.rb:46:in `find'
        2: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/class_loader.rb:54:in `resolve'
        1: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/class_loader.rb:54:in `path2class'
ArgumentError (undefined class/module Logger::SimpleFormatter)
```

Rails.logger is:

```
irb(main):002:0> Rails.logger
=> #<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x0000563a356d7070 @level=2, @progname=nil, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x0000563a356d6e40 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=#<ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x0000563a356d6be8 @datetime_format=nil>, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x0000563a356d6d78 @shift_period_suffix=nil, @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<IO:<STDOUT>>, @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x0000563a356d6c88>>, @local_levels=#<ThreadSafe::Cache:0x0000563a356d6ad0 @backend={}, @default_proc=nil>>
```

I am aware that Logger::SimpleFormatter was removed from rails 4.1, and I should be using ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter. I understand that the production log_formatter defaults to Logger::Formatter. I have tried numerous config variations in config/environments/production.rb, to no avail, and also adding the the rails_12factor gem, which switches the Rails.logger to:

```
<RailsStdoutLogging::StdoutLogger:0x000055fbb41bca28 @level=2, @progname=nil, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x000055fbb41bc988 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=#<ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x000055fbb41bc8c0 @datetime_format=nil>, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x000055fbb41bc938 @shift_period_suffix=nil, @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<IO:<STDOUT>>, @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x000055fbb41bc8e8>>, @local_levels=#<ThreadSafe::Cache:0x000055fbb41bc898 @backend={}, @default_proc=nil>>
```

If I introduce the my own Logger::SimpleFormatter class, inheriting from ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter, it solves the issue, but the error moves to:

```
undefined class/module Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was we had legacy Braintree objects in the database which were calling the rails 3 logger when we actioned the ES import

Comment: Hello kojo jo! As this question and answer is (and most likely will be) only relevant to yourself, it would be better to remove both of them as this site is meant to provide Q&A relevant to many people.

Comment: Hi @ElmarZander, as I have resolved the issue, personally it would not affect me if it is removed. I was not able to find any guidance online in relation to the issue, nor did it attract any replies, so perhaps leaving it up might help a few people who are in the same boat, it is unlikely I am the only person affected by this...